# Activity Transition from A -> B and lifecycle sequence

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Why activity lifecycle transition from `Activity A` to `Activity B` is like `onPause(A)` -> `onCreate(B)`-> `onStart(B)` -> `onResume(B)` -> `onStop(A)` 
what is  reason behind this sequence?

Why not it is like firstly all method of `Activity A` will execute and then `Activity B` method will start?

Answer (score 3):

You don't killed the `Activity A`, so, it continue "living" and is `overlapping` by `Activity B`

Comment: but why it is so,why not activity a get killed,what is actual reason of following this pattern?

Comment: Use `finish()` on `Activity A` when start `Activity B`. The reason: an Activity not will close automatically if you not finish them yourself

Comment: why activity is not firstly going to background and then activity b is launching ,why it is firstly going to on pause and after activity b come to foreground ,it goes to background?

Comment: @RahulMahajan see it link about [Android Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)